# generating random algebraic matrix using elementary operations

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, programming, algebraic-manipulation, algebra

I generate several algebraic matrices of 12x12 where each element is a combination no repeat of the variables x, y, z and operations +, -, *, /, power, establishment (square root), any of them or any of them

example: [x + y + z, x ^ 2 + y-z, (x + y + z) ^ 2, .....]etc.

Comment: So, any algebraic expression like $\sqrt{1 - x^2 +y}$ or $\frac{1+x}{2+y^2}$ can be an element?

Comment: Isn't x^2 a "repeat" of x since it is x*x?

Comment: so not so complex, but may be future options

Comment: By saying "no repeat"... Do you want no exact duplicates or what?

Comment: yes,  example      x/y    and 2x/2y  not

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are a lot of ways to generate random functions. Here's one:

```
a := RandomChoice[{Times, Plus}] @@ (RandomChoice[{Sqrt, Identity, Power}] /@ 
  (RandomSample[{x, y, z}, 3] RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 3])^RandomInteger[{-3, 3}, 3]);
```

To make a matrix of such functions:

```
Table[a, 3, 3] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Of course the output is different each time. Thanks to `Bill` (not me -- the true `bill s`) for pointing out that `Table[a, {i, 3}, {j, 3}]` is required for versions before 10.2.

Comment: error: Argument 3 at position 2 does not have the correct form for an iterator. >> ??????

Comment: @zeros If you click on https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html and you click on "Updated Show Changes" in the upper right corner then it will show that they changed the syntax in 10.2 to accept Table[expr,n] in addition to the older Table[expr,{n}] form. Snews to me.

Comment: Thanks, I can explain this part of the code
@@  and   

/ @

. Other operations can mix ??

Comment: ok con explain,...Other operations can mix ??